# transform don't work in transformed element(3d)

Tags: html, css, 3d

please refer to this [`fiddle`]
(https://jsfiddle.net/hymin/gbsdafjg/2/)

I have four elements with 3d transformed into a cube, which are attached on a `container` element.

The purpose of setting up the `container` element is that when I `rotateX` the `container`, (I expect) the `roller` elements will rotate along with it, thus creating a 3d rotate effect and avoiding writing `transform` property for each of them.

the problem is that when I apply the 3d transform CSS rule on the `container` element, all transform effects on the `roller` elements disappeared.

Please help! And, if this is the normal behavior, is there any way to work around this other than applying transform property on all four(maybe more in the future) `roller` elements?

Thanks!

update#1

if you added a `perspective` CSS rule on the `container` element, the visual 3d effect on the `roller` won't disappear when you 3d transform the `container`. however everything seems to be flattened. try it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

a CSS rule `transform-style:preserve-3d` will solve this problem.